# update conda, conda breaks

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I updated anaconda to version to conda 4.3.8. Big mistake. Now I can't import any modules in a jupyter notebook.

I think the problem is the path. `python --version` is Python 2.7.10, but I also have a Python 3.5 environment (made from `conda create -n python35 python=3.5 anaconda`). Thing is, before the update, BOTH WORKED FINE.

Now I can only import modules if I `source activate python35` and then `jupyter notebook`. Path when I am in the python35 environment: `'/Users/FirstLast/anaconda/bin/python'`. When I am not in that environment:  `'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'`. Clearly a path issue.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen simply by updating the bloody thing?
2. How does one resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must have selected the "Add to PATH" option while installing or updating. This used to be the default but is no longer recommended.

Selecting the Add to PATH option adds the path to your .bash_profile. Remove the path to Anaconda by editing your bash profile, see 
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#removing-anaconda-path-from-bash-profile